# How to make this Eloquent relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table called users with a column username. Another table called students with a column code. I have made a hasMany relationship in User model like below and it's working fine.

```
public function students()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Student::class,'code','username');
}
```

I have another table called institutes where a column is similar to students table named inst. I need to show data from institutes table while showing data of an user. How to make this relationship?

users table

username|mobile|address|password

students table

username|name|inst|roll|reg

institutes table

name|inst|address|phone

This is my home controller

```
public function index()
{
     $admins = User::where('username','=',Auth::user()->username)->get();
     return view('home', compact('admins'));
}
```

And this is my view

```
@foreach($admins as $key => $admin)            
   @foreach($admin->students as $student)
      {{ $student->reg }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add migration to your Students table :

   ```
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
   ```
2. Update your model User on students method :

   ```
   return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
   ```
3. Add "with method"

   $admins = User::where('username','=',Auth::user()->username)->with('students')->get();

Comment: I am working on existing database where tables are filled with data.